# Return parameter by pointer in function of C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following type definition.

```
typedef USHORT HSERVICE;
typedef HSERVICE * LPHSERVICE;
```

By task I have to use **LPHSERVICE** to obtain the value 10. And it cannot be changed.

I need help to do it. Thank you!

**C++ code**

```
typedef USHORT HSERVICE;
typedef HSERVICE * LPHSERVICE;

void func(LPHSERVICE lphService);

int main()
{
  LPHSERVICE lphService;

  func(lphService);

  // I need to see 10 in lphService

  return 0;
}

void func(LPHSERVICE lphService)
{
  HSERVICE hService;
  hService = 10;

  lphService = &hService; // Not working
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of "not working"? What are these "USHORT" and "HSERVICE" types? They are not standard C++, so much is sure, but I guess they could be removed.

Comment: Please avoid the windows-api programming style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simnulating with integers, this is what you should do.
There are a couple of problems with your code:

1 - you can't point to a local variable because its address will be rendered invalid upon function epilogue.
To keep the variable inside the function, you have to put it on the heap, and then get its address.
**(note the call to `free()` at the end of main)**

2 - just because you are working with a pointer, it does not mean that you can change its content inside the function and the changes will be reflected outside, you must supply the adderess of the pointer.

```
typedef int HSERVICE;
typedef int* LPHSERVICE;

void func(LPHSERVICE*);

int main()
{


  LPHSERVICE lphService = 0;

 func(&lphService);

  printf("%d", *lphService);

  delete lphService;

  return 0;  
}


void func(LPHSERVICE* lphService)
{
  HSERVICE* hService = new HSERVICE;
  *hService = 10;

  *lphService = hService;
}
```

Comment: Don't mix `new` and `free`.

Comment: new followed by free - no good (also it is a bad pattern to allocate and return the allocated result, if the function is no allocator function )

Comment: @DieterLücking IronMensan already pointed that out and I fixed it. Also, the variable is being placed on the heap, there is no problem referencing it as long as it is cleaned up afterwards

Comment: Still it makes me shiver not to see an 'allocate_service' withe a corresponding 'deallocate_service' function. (a std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr would fix it easily)

Answer (score 1):

`LPHSERVICE` is a pointer type so you can write to directly like this:

```
void func(LPHSERVICE lphService)
{
    *lphService = 10;
}
```

But this will crash because `main` isn't allocating an `HSERVICE` so that will have to change to:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    HSERVICE hService;
    LPHSERVICE lphService = &hService;

    func(lphService);

    // I need to see 10 in lphService
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! The point is that `hService` is gonna be initialized and after this I have to initialize `lphService ``. Would you mind to rewrite your code according this condition, please? Thank you!

Comment: You can create hservice on the heap inside the function, but I really don't see the point. The problem he solved here is that you were trying to reference a local variable, and such variables are destroyed after the function returns.

Comment: @Dimi `lphService` is a pointer so you have to at least allocate an `HSERVICE` before you can initialize it to a non-NULL value.  I don't understand what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found solution that is working fine.

```
typedef USHORT HSERVICE;
typedef HSERVICE * LPHSERVICE;

void func(LPHSERVICE &lphService,  HSERVICE hService);

int main()
{
  HSERVICE hService;
  hService = 0;

  LPHSERVICE lphService;

  func(lphService, hService);

  int d;
  d = *lphService;


  return 0;
}

void func(LPHSERVICE &lphService,  HSERVICE hService)
{
    hService = 10;
    lphService = &hService;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really work.  It's invoking undefined behavior and only appears to work because you're not calling any other functions and the `HSERVICE` created on the stack hasn't been touched.  If you change the second parameter of `func` to `HSERVICE & hService`, then it will be safe.